# Why Jenkins requires login password for sonar 6.2?

Tags: jenkins, sonarqube, jenkins-pipeline, sonarqube-scan

Using pipeline code,

```
withSonarQubeEnv {
        dir ('/mydirectory/') {
            sh "'${mvnHome}/bin/mvn' org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:3.2:sonar -Dsonar.projectKey=somemykey -Dsonar.projectName=somemyname"
        }
```

Which outputs:

```
Failed to execute goal org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:3.2:sonar (default-cli) on project myproject: Not authorized. Please check the properties sonar.login and sonar.password.
```

If that is expected behavior then how to avoid pasting login and password? If not what is the root cause of it? Is it a problem with Sonar server configuration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the global level you should configure your server instance to include an [analysis token](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/User+Token) from a user with [Global Execute Analysis](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Authorization#Authorization-GlobalPermissions) permissions. Either that, or include a project-specific user token at the analysis level.

The error message asking for login/password is a bit outmoded. You *can* still use login/password, but analysis token is the recommended way.

Comment: Thank you that worked. Although I still have a problem with failing waitForQualityGate: Wait for SonarQube analysis to be completed and return quality gate status

Comment: I receive "org.sonarqube.ws.client.HttpException: Error 401 on <link to sonar>" on waitForQualityGate() despite that a webhook is set

Comment: That looks to me like a different question @koller23 :-)

Comment: Hi @Ann, I have a similar issue. I have configured the SonarQube server instance in jenkins and added the following groovy script to my jenkinsfile :   `stage('SonarQube analysis') {
         tools {
                   jdk "jdk-8u152"
                }
         steps {
       withSonarQubeEnv('MySonar') {
          sh 'mvn sonar:sonar -Dsonar.login=XXXX'
       }
      }
    }` with : `[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:3.2:sonar (default-cli) on project MyProject: Not authorized. Please check the properties sonar.login and sonar.password.`